# Acer laptop keyboard not working?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, kde, laptop, acer

My Acer laptop keyboard not working after shutdown. Now I use USB keyboard but i need fix problem?

I want know the type of problem (software or hardware).

**I use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with kde plasma 5.12.9**

**xinput**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK USB Keyboard                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK USB Keyboard                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root
```

**dmesg**

http://codepad.org/8yyGcQ9X

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I just cleaned my keyboard and it doesn't work since then. I tried Fn+ScrLk, Ctrl+Alt+L and all kinds of stuff, no luck.